# Run method on Python Bottle server shutdown

Tags: python, multithreading, bottle

I'm working on a small python app controlled by a web page via the Bottle framework.
Problem is that I am sometimes running threads in the background but if the Bottle instance is shutdown, via Ctrl+C for example, it just hangs because those threads are never told to quit.
Is there a way to catch the Bottle server shutdown and call a method to do some cleanup?

Comment: Maybe you can just install a signal handler for the CTRL-C event and then do your cleanup. http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html

Comment: Good thought... would be great if I could handle any Bottle shutdown even though.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you want `daemon` threads?  (See my answer below--and my other two as well.  Sorry, I got carried away thinking about this! :)

Comment: What did you end up using?

Answer (score 2):

`try`/`finally`:

```
# start threads here

try:
    bottle.run(...)  # or app.run(...)

finally:
    # clean up (join) threads here
```

---

EDIT: Thanks to @linusg for correctly pointing out that the try block isn't even needed. Better to just use:

```
# start threads here

bottle.run(...)  # or app.run(...)

# if we reach here, run has exited (Ctrl-C)

# clean up (join) threads here
```

Comment: Nope. run() does not throw an exception on Ctrl-C, so the try/finally isn't just needed. Instead, this would do it: `# Start threads; bottle.run(...); #Clean up`!

Comment: @linusg I just verified that you're indeed correct. Answer edited to reflect your improvement. Thanks!

Comment: Great, so this answer is valid :)

Answer (score 0):

`__del__`.

Something like:

```
class MyApp(bottle.Bottle):
    def __del__(self):
        # clean up threads here

# from here it's just business as usual
app = MyApp()

@app.route('/')
def home()
    return 'hello, world.\n'

app.run('127.0.0.1', 8080)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a context manager:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
#Code for server goes here

@contextmanager
def server_with_threads():
    try:
        spawn_thread_things()
        yield MyServer()
    finally:
        close_thready_things()

#Or maybe here

with server_with_threads() as server:
    server.run('127.0.0.1', 8080)
```

Once your server shuts down gracefully, or an exception is thrown (you exit the with block, basically), then it will hit the `finally` condition, and cleanup your threads.

Another option is [atexit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your threads don't need to shut down gracefully, then just make them [daemon](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) threads and your process will exit cleanly with no further changes.

> A thread can be flagged as a “daemon thread”. The significance of this
>   flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads
>   are left. The initial value is inherited from the creating thread. The
>   flag can be set through the daemon property.

```
t = threading.Thread(target=myfunc)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

# because t is a daemon thread, no need to join it at process exit.
```

N.B., The wording of your question implies that your real problem is that they're causing your process to hang on exit, not that they need to free resources, but it's worth pointing this out:

> Note: Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources
>   (such as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released
>   properly.